# Edit method for Employee Store.(Using Hashmap)

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, edit

Hey can anyone help me understand how to do an edit method for my company application.  I had previously asked for help with a search method.  And i think the edit method might involve the search method.

Here is my code:

```
EmployeeStore.

//Imports.
import java.util.HashMap;
//********************************************************************
public class EmployeeStore
{
    HashMap<String, Employee> map;

//Constructor.  
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    }
//********************************************************************
//Hashmap Methods.
//Add to the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void add(Employee employee)
    {

        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Remove from the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void remove(String key)
    {
      //Remove the Employee by name.
        map.remove(key);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Clear the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void clear()
    {
        map.clear();
    }
    //********************************************************************
//Print the Hashmap : Employee. 
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Employee's in the Company.********");
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            //System.out.println(employee); to print the toString of Employee class
            //or:
            System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + employee.getEmployeeName());
            System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + employee.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println("E-mail:\t"+ employee.getEmployeeEmail());
        }

    }
    public Employee get(String name){
        return map.get(name);
    }
    /*public void searchByName ()
    {
        //(for(Employee e : map.values()) {...}) 
        //and check for each employee if his/her email matches the searched value
        for(Employee e : map.values())
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            map.equals(getClass());

        }
    }*/
//********************************************************************
    public Employee searchByName(String name) 
    {
        Employee employee = map.get(name);    
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }
//********************************************************************

    public Employee searchByEmail(String email) 
    {
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            if (email.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail()))
            {
                System.out.println(employee);
                return employee;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
//********************************************************************





//********************************************************************  
//********************************************************************


}
```

Employee class.

```
//Imports:

//********************************************************************
//Employee Class.
public class Employee
{
//Variables.
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//********************************************************************  
//Constructor.
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//********************************************************************
//Getters.
    public String getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
//********************************************************************
//toString method.
    public String toString() {
        return "\t\t\tEmployee\n" +
                "********************************************************************\n"+
                "Employee Name: "+ employeeName +"\n"+ 
                "Employee Id: " + employeeId +"\n"+  
                "Employee Email: " + employeeEmail;
    }
//********************************************************************





}
```

Comment: do you want to edit by emp-name or by emp-object?

Comment: what do you mean by "edit method"? a method that let you change a previously stored Employee instance?

Comment: Sorry.  Yes i want to edit name, id and email.

Comment: If you are editing id or email(which is not the key of the map), you don't need to update the map as long as you update those fields of the `Employee` object. If you are eding the name, then you will have to remove the entry with the old employee name, and insert a new one to the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the put method of java's HashMap for this as well. [From the API for HashMap's put method:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

> If the map previously contained a mapping for this key, the old value is replaced.

So, something like:

```
public void edit(Employee employee)
{
    map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
}
```

And then in the other code:

```
Employee employee = getEmployeeByName("Someniceemployeename");
if (employee != null)
{
    employee.setEmployeeEmail("awesomeness@stackoverflow.com");
    edit(employee);
}
```

As for editing the ID of an employee, you need to take some additional precautions. First, you want to make sure that the map contains the ID you want to edit (as usual). Second, when "editing" the ID you need to first remove the old employee instance from the map (with the old ID) and then add the new employee with put.

Comment: Updated for ID. I left the code out for some exercising fun. :)

Comment: lol thanks.  I didnt think it would be so easy i always over complicate java.